# Android Google Play Services GPS not sending location

Tags: java, android, gps

I've make an application that could track the user's location but sometimes the GPS doesn't seem to send the location.

Also it doesn't seem the GPS get disconnected because I've put logs for that and there is no log indicating a gps disconnect.

It just looks like it stop calling the `onLocationChanged` for some sometime then it works again.

Here is an example of the issue. As you can see I'm going through buildings ....

I've even put a partial wake lock after some research online but it doesn't seem to work.

[image]

So what I do is start my application and then push the power button on my phone to turn the screen off and start driving. Arriving at destination I open the app and stop my application.

It doesn't happen all the time.

Any idea on what could be causing this?

Thanks,

Here is the code :

```
public class LocationService extends Service implements
ConnectionCallbacks,
OnConnectionFailedListener,
LocationListener {

    private static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LocationService.class);

    private final IBinder _binder = new LocalBinder();

    private LocationClient _locationClient;
    private LocationRequest REQUEST = LocationRequest.create()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
            .setInterval(5000)
            .setFastestInterval(1000)
            .setSmallestDisplacement(5);

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public LocationService getService() {
            return LocationService.this;
        }
    }

    private PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        LOGGER.debug("onCreate");

        PowerManager mgr = (PowerManager)this.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = mgr.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "Wake Lock");
    }

    public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        LOGGER.debug("onStartCommand");

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return _binder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy(); 

        LOGGER.debug("onDestroy");

        if(_locationClient != null) {
            stopAcquiringLocation();
            _locationClient = null;
        }

        if(wakeLock.isHeld())
            wakeLock.release();
    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        LOGGER.debug("location: "+location.getLatitude()+","+location.getLongitude() +" Accurracy: "+location.getAccuracy() + " Time:"+new Date(location.getTime()));

        if(location.getAccuracy() <= 15) {
            //Save the location
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        LOGGER.info("GPS Connected");

        // Request location updates using static settings
        getLocationClient().requestLocationUpdates(REQUEST, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {
        LOGGER.info("GPS Disconnected");

        if(_locationClient != null) {
            stopAcquiringLocation();
            _locationClient = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        LOGGER.info("GPS ConnectionFailed "+connectionResult.toString());
    }



    private LocationClient getLocationClient()
    {
        if(_locationClient == null)
            _locationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);

        return _locationClient;
    }

    public void startAcquiringLocation() {
        if(Util.IsGooglePlayServiceAvailable(this)) {
            if (!getLocationClient().isConnected() || !getLocationClient().isConnecting()) {
                LOGGER.debug("getLocationClient().connect()");

                getLocationClient().connect();

                if(wakeLock.isHeld() == false)
                    wakeLock.acquire();
            }
        }
        else {
            LOGGER.warn("NO Google Play Services Available");
        }
    }

    public void stopAcquiringLocation() {
        if(Util.IsGooglePlayServiceAvailable(this)) {
            if (getLocationClient().isConnected() || getLocationClient().isConnecting()) {
                getLocationClient().removeLocationUpdates(this);
                getLocationClient().disconnect();

                LOGGER.debug("getLocationClient().disconnect()");

                if(wakeLock.isHeld())
                    wakeLock.release();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say anything without some code. First thing I would try - as you are already testing your app outside - is using another, similar app and see, if there is a problem with your app or a hardware issue with your inbuilt GPS.

The values of `MIN_DISTANCE_FOR_UPDATES` and `MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES` are reasonable?

Energy saving mode enabled in your phone can also lead to a less frequent GPS position updates.

I think, for more suggestions, some code is required.

Comment: My phone is a oneplus one, it might be a hardware issue, maybe weather/clouds. The GPS Mode on the phone is set at High Accuracy. and the minimum distance is 5 meters and interval are at 5 seconds. I've added the code.

Comment: I don't see what could cause this behaviour. And to be honest, I needed to see your code to estimate your level of programming and I'm no better than this. But I'm missing one thing here: I needed to set `criteria`, which sets the type of positioning: GPS or network provider. And that I don't see in your code. Do you really use GPS?

Comment: I'm using the Location API from google play services SDK. What you are talking about is the android.location package. I believe they are now recommending to use the Location API over the android.location package.

Comment: oh man a little bit more research and now it looks like its now recommended to use the GoogleApiClient instead of the LocationClient as it is now deprecated. Looking at the logs, I am seeing why I have this issue. A lot of the gps points given has a very bad Accuracy. I'm ignoring all the location of an accuracy higher than 15. Now the question is why so many bad accuracy location ?

Answer (score 0):

Also I suggest to try to make your tests in an area where the buildings are low (1-2 floors) so you will not have "lost of signal" for the GPS itself.
Try to log all the gps events and also see in the log what is happening.

Also in GPS you have a precision of at least 10 m. Usual you can get a better position because of the limitations that are in the data in purpose.

daniel